# Show image by image on hover with js

Tags: javascript, html

I am just a junior programmer with JavaScript.
I want to show 4 images after eachother when you hover on a nav link. It works when the cursor comes through the left side, but when it comes from the top, bottom or right side, it doesn't work. It doesn't recognize the `src=""` part. Does somebody knows how to fix this?

This code below is the `<li>` in my Bootstrap 5.0 navbar.

```
<li class="nav-item px-3" id="navLink1" style="position: relative">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/1x1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; transform: translateY(-100%)">
    <a class="nav-link fs-5" aria-current="page" href="?page=home">Over Ons</a>
</li>
```

This code is my JavaScript code

```
images[0] = ["img/photo1.png", "1rem", "-2rem"];
images[1] = ["img/photo2.png", "2rem", "-2.5rem"];
images[2] = ["img/photo3.png", "3rem", "-3rem"];
images[3] = ["img/photo4.png", "4rem", "-3.5rem"];

let i = 0;

let timer = 0;

function changeImage(param) {
    console.log(param);
    param.children[0].src = images[i][0];
    param.children[0].style.maxWidth = images[i][1];
    param.children[0].style.left = images[i][2];

    i++;
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
}

$('#navLink1').hover(function (ev) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        changeImage(ev.target);
    }, 600);

}, function (ev) {
    clearInterval(timer);

});
```

Comment: Hi Stijn! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please add a [mre]? Take a look at [ask] if you have any further questions!

Comment: Log the `ev.target` in your hover callback, pretty sure you will see that it is not the same element in those two cases.

Comment: @CBroe It indeed is true that when console logging the ev it shows up as the a tag inside my li, while when coming from the left it shows the li tag I need. Do you have any idea how I could do this whilst still keeping it dynamic?

Comment: You could check the `nodeName` of the target, and if that is not `LI`, then you know that you are on one of the children, and need to move up one level (only one, since you have no nested children here), via `parentNode`.

Comment: @CBroe Kind of foolish of me to not think of that. Thank you though for fixing my problem. I'd upvote your comment if I could but this fixed the problem.